# How do I pass an immediate 4 bit value to the last argument of _mm256_blend_pd

Tags: c++, gcc, avx

I'm trying to use _mm256_blend_pd, but I keep encountering a compiler error. In this case, the error is that gcc wants "the last argument must be a 4-bit immediate". I can successfully pass in a hard coded value, but any calculated value produces the error.

Here is a contrived and useless program that demonstrates the error. I run into the error with gcc 4.6.3 and gcc 4.8.3.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    __m256d zeroHit = {0};
    int j=rand()%3;
    int imm=(0x01);
    // This line will compile
    _mm256_store_pd(0,_mm256_blend_pd(zeroHit,*reinterpret_cast<__m256d*>(0),imm&0x0F)); 
    imm=(0x01 & (j!=0));
    // This line will produce the error
    _mm256_store_pd(0,_mm256_blend_pd(zeroHit,*reinterpret_cast<__m256d*>(0),imm&0x0F));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's called an "immediate" for a reason. It needs to be a compile time constant.

Comment: @Mysticial: To be honest I don't think the name is all that intuitive. =P

Comment: @Mehrdad That's true. I guess I've been doing this for so long that I take the lingo for granted. :)

Comment: Oh thanks, I should have thought of that type of limitation.

Comment: FYI "immediate" is assembler terminology which has percolated up via intrinsics.

Comment: Yep, I'm ashamed to say I didn't think of the connection after having come of age with the 6502 in the Apple ][.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an "immediate" for a reason. It needs to be a compile time constant. –  Mysticial